# How does ssh handle a connection to a server in a LAN sharing a public IP

Tags: networking, ssh

Let's say that I have some servers A and B in a LAN behind a classic router. My servers A and B share the same public IPv4 address, the one of my router.

I want to connect via ssh on server A from my laptop which is outside of the LAN, e.g.:

```
ssh me@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

How can it work since in theory both A and B are not distinguishable ? I have seen such setups work with for instance noip services, but this is bugging me.

Comment: You need to create a DNAT port redirect on the router, forwarding an arbitrary WAN-side port number to Server A's LAN IP and SSH port.  _**Do NOT forward WAN-side port `22`**_, as ports like `22`, `23`, `1194`, etc. shouldn't be exposed to WAN due to the hundreds to thousands of requests each will receive daily from port scanners... the higher the WAN-side port the better, as port scanners normally don't scan all 65,535 ports.  _(for example, forward WAN-side port `40506` to LAN `192.168.1.2` port `22`)_

Comment: It will not work at all because the public IP belongs to your router and your router usually has no ssh service running. You can only make it work by configuring your router to send all packets for the ssh port 22 to one internal computer (A or B for example)

Comment: Basically [DNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#DNAT), [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). Note SSH (the protocol; or `ssh` – the program) does not need to care about this because it works in a different layer.